# Prevent a form field from displaying in the browser

Tags: python, html, django

I have a form and want that the user field should not be displayed.

models.py

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    question=models.TextField(max_length=500)
    created_date=models.DateTimeField('date created')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s%s" %(self.question,self.created_date)

class QuestionsForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Questions
        widgets = {
            'question': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add question here'})
        }
        exclude=('user',)
```

I tried exclude but the field still appears. how to do it??

Comment: it should be within `Meta` class, your code suggests its outside of it. Is that typo here or in your code also?

Comment: You got it right, the only problem is your indentation.

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to your indentation:

```
class QuestionsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        widgets = {
            'question': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add question here'})
        }
        exclude=('user',)
```